# How to link data between spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I have one data sheet that has two columns of numbers (participant id #s and then participant sex coded as 1 or 2) linked together.

In my other sheet, I have the participant id #s but not the sex column.

I need to match those ids with the sex in this other sheet, but many participants dropped out before the end of the study, so I cannot simply sort smallest to largest and paste the column of sex information.

So, how can I pair the sex information with ids in this other sheet, using the information from the first sheet? Hopefully that makes sense, I will clarify if needed.

Comment: You will want to use VLOOKUP().  Google it,  there are many tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: Better to learn INDEX MATCH. Google that instead

Answer (score 0):

please use

sheet1:
column A = ID's
column B = SEX

sheet2:
column A = ID's
column B = formula below

in both sheets row 1 = headers

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,sheet1!A:B,2,0)
```